# Can I remove entries in LinkedHashMap<> for array of keys and not a single entry for a single key?

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

I use `LinkedHashMap<>` in my Android application and the problem I want to delete several entries from it at once.In Objective-C there is a method `removeObjectsForKeys` which accepts array of keys and remove entries corresponded to the keys in that array - is there something similar to it in Java? Or I can only use `remove(Object key)`and delete single entry for single key?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this

```
map.keySet().removeAll(Arrays.asList(arr))
```